# Не работает отладка юнит-тестов NUnit в Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, юнит-тесты, nunit

Добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой в работе Visual Studio 2017 Professional. Версия 15.2. Не запускаются юнит-тесты NUnit (версия 3.7) в режиме `Debug test`. При этом если выбирать команду `Run test`, то все работает. В консоль при этом печатается следующее:

> ------ Run test started ------
>   Process with an Id of -1 is not running.
>   ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:01,0731073) ==========

С чем может быть связана такая проблема? Возможно кто-то сталкивался с этим, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Надеюсь закрыть VS/перезагрузиться уже пробовали? Иногда в сырых версиях VS это помогало. А так полный сброс настроек и перeустановка должны помочь,

Comment: Да, конечно. Только переустановку не пробовал выполнять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Попробуйте сделать очистку решения, закрыть студию, удалить все папки bin и obj, запустить студию и перекомпилировать проект.
2. Проверьте, что у зависимостей проектов (References/Ссылки) нет жёлтых треугольничков.
3. Проверьте, что подключен nuget пакет NUnit3TestAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно тесты не запускаются, если разрядность проекта не совпадает с разрядностью тестов.
Проверьте в настройках: Test - Test settings - Default Processor Architecture. Должно совпадать с тем, что указано в свойствах проекта: Project - <имя проекта> properties - Build - Platform target

Comment: Спасибо, это к сожалению никак не повлияло на запуск тестов в режиме отладки. При этом я выбирал и x86 и x64.